# Is it possible to write a lucene search query with multiple AND / OR terms on Lucene Fields?

Tags: lucene

According to this page:

http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html

you can do searches like

title:"The Right Way" AND text:go

But when i do something like:

title:"The Right Way" OR title:"Home" I get no results even though I know there are pages with the title "Home".

How do I build a Lucene Query to do multiple ORs/ANDs for the same field ?

Comment: That query looks fine to me.  Do you get any results for the simpler query  `title:Home` ?

Answer (score 0):

When debugging queries, I always use [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/). Luke lets you see exactly how Lucene interprets your query (as the ANDs and ORs are turned into SHOULDs and MUSTs).

Answer (score 0):

If you print out Query `queryParser.parse("title:\"The Right Way\" OR title:\"Home\"")` by `StandardAnalyzer`, the result is Query is [*title:"the right way" **title:home***]